# How to capture a StoredProcedureParameterCollection for ServerA's Sp to update ServerB

Tags: smo

VS2010 
I am reading any existing params and I want to load them into a 
ByRef params As StoredProcedureParameterCollection for use later.

As the code runs I get a null exception error and I cannot understand why?  p has values for use  to param and param has values for params.

```
For Each p As StoredProcedureParameter In spF.Parameters
    Dim param As StoredProcedureParameter = New StoredProcedureParameter(spF, p.Name, p.DataType)

    params.Add(Add(param, cnt))  '  << Get a null exception here??
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next
```

Anyone else done this?  Please don't say buy red-gate.  That door slammed on my fingers long ago.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take the params from the From server and pass over to the To server you need to create a standalone paramsCollection

Dim paramsF as StoredProcedureParameterCollection

spF is the loaded up sp of the From db.

paramsF = spF.Parameters  'nothing to new up here just copy it outright!

As you build up the layers to the spT with the database, the script as well as the params:

```
        For Each p As StoredProcedureParameter In paramsF
            Dim pp As StoredProcedureParameter
            pp = New StoredProcedureParameter(spT, p.Name, p.DataType)
            spT.Parameters.Add(pp)
        Next
```